# Cannot access HTTP response headers from server on Angular 5 client

Tags: typescript, spring-boot, angular5

I have a spring boot server that is accessed using an Angular 5 frontend. The backend server is being accessed by using a proxy config that looks like this:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8085",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

The server is setting a few headers and returns the response in the form of a ResponseEntity. This is for a GET request that is supposed to return a stream for download.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Disposition, Content-Length");
                    headers.add("Content-Type","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FILE_NAME);
.
.
<some-logic-here>
.
.
return new ResponseEntity<>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

On debugging the application through Chrome, I can see the data being returned, along with the headers but for some reason only the content-type header is being read and not the other ones.

The client code to send the request is as such:

```
export interface FileResult {
  body: any[];
  headers: {};
}

getFileByteArray(url: string): Observable<FileResult> {
    return this.http.get<FileResult>(this.baseUrl + url, this.options);
  }

this.service.getFileByteArray(url).subscribe(fileResult => {
        this.showSpinner = false;
        //var filename = fileResult.headers; <- This is where the headers are not visible
        this.downloadFile(fileResult.body, 'temp');
})
```

Response headers being returned as viewed through Chrome debugger

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
allow-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, Content-Type, Content-Disposition, Content-Length
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Type, Content-Disposition, Content-Length
content-disposition: attachment; filename=Stats_Workbook_01-SEP-2018_01-SEP-2018.xlsx
content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
content-length: 9803
connection: close
```

Not sure why they are being repeated twice in the above snippet.